# What's the relationship between ContainerD and Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, open-source

I'm aware that Kubernetes uses `containerd` internally and that `containerd` is part of Docker.  Does that mean that Kubernetes only uses certain parts of Docker to provide orchestration of containers? Additionally, how does `runc` fit into this ecosystem, I'm aware Kubernetes uses it because CVEs affecting `runc` impact Kubernetes.

I've not been able to find out what the technical components of Kubernetes are; there are plenty of diagrams out there showing the logical elements (i.e. masters, nodes, kubelets, deployments, services, pods, etc.). However, I'm trying to get into the details a bit more and understand what parts make up Kubernetes.

Is it possible to describe how Kubernetes is constructed from its components such as `runc`, `containerd` and Docker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646558/8464140.

Answer (score 9):

[Containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd) is a daemon for running containers.  The [Docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/what-is-containerd-runtime/) has a nice write up explaining how this fits into Docker.  While containerd is used in Docker, it can also be used as a daemon for other container solutions.  Containerd requires runc in order to function.

[runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) as defined by the project is a "CLI tool for spawning and running containers according to the OCI specification".

These tools are designed to follow the [Open Container Initiative](https://opencontainers.org/about/overview/) (OCI) specifications.  This has become a standard and defines how Docker and other tooling interacts with containerd and runc.

When you look at most Kubernetes diagrams they will not show `containerd` or `runc` as they are abstracted away into the container engine you use (e.g., Docker, rkt).  Because Kubernetes uses `containerd`, it will also use `runc`.  This is what allows multiple container solutions that follow OCI specifications to integrate with Kubernetes.

So yes, you could break down how part of Kubernetes is built by looking at `runc`, `containerd`, and the container engine.